# Nested for loop to numpy convolve

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

How can I improve the speed of this function?

```
def foo(mri_data, radius):

    mask = mri_data.copy()

    ny = len(mri_data[0,:])
    nx = len(mri_data[:])

    for y in xrange(0, ny):
        for x in xrange(0, nx):
            if (mri_data[x-radius:x+radius,y-radius:y+radius] != 1.0).all():
                mask[x,y] = 0.0                    
    return mask.copy()
```

It takes in image slices in the form of a numpy array. Iterates through each pixels and tests a bounding box around that pixel. If no values in the box are equal to 1 than we discard that pixel by setting it to 0.

I've been told I can use `numpy.convolve` but I am uncertain how this relates.

EDIT: The images values are in binary range so lowest value is 0.0 and max value is 1.0. With values in between ex: 0.767.

Comment: Be careful with the edges. If you have e.g. `radius=3` and `mri_data = np.arange(8)` then your first window is `mri_data[-3:3]` which returns an empty array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the cases where you can abuse convolution. I wouldn't use it, but the boundaries are otherwise tedious...

```
from scipy.ndimage import convolve

not_one = (mri_data != 1.0) # are you sure you want to compare with float like that?!

conv = convolve(not_one, np.ones((2*radius, 2*radius)))
all_not_one = (conv == (2*radius)**2)

mask[all_not_one] = 0
```

Should do the same thing really...

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is called a `binary_dilation` but there is a small bug in your code. Specifically you're getting negative indices when x, y are smaller than radius. These negative numbers are interpreted using numpy indexing rules, which is not what you want here [more on indexing here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html), giving you the wrong result on two edges of your image.

Here is some code that uses binary dilation to accomplish the same thing, and fix the above mentioned bug.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import binary_dilation

def foo(mri_data, radius):
    structure = np.ones((2*radius, 2*radius))
    # I set the origin here to match your code
    mask = binary_dilation(mri_data == 1, structure, origin=-1)
    return np.where(mask, mri_data, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Bi Rico. I was unaware that this sort of threshold I made was already a filter. I will have to try your solution as well.